# How to check the version of the dynamic linker?

Tags: linux, libraries

If I run a binary *compiled on a newer Linux distro* on an older Linux distro, I may get an error like this:

> error while loading shared
>   libraries: requires glibc 2.5 or later
>   dynamic linker

How can I check the version of the dynamic linker in a Linux system? Is it provided by a package? If so, what's the name of the package?

And 2 theoretical questions:

- Is it possible to update the dynamic linker? (I don't think I'm going to do this but I just want to know)
- Is it possible to use a dynamic linker outside of the system paths? (e.g. one that is compiled/installed by a unprivileged user)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loader is provided by glibc. Look for `/lib{,64}/ld-*.so`. The number after the dash is the version of glibc that provides it. Updating glibc will provide a newer linker.

Comment: I see. If so, can I use an alternate linker by specifying LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: It's the loader that reads and processes the `$LD_*` variables in the first place.

Comment: I used a hex editor to change the hard-coded loader path from `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` to a newer `ld.so`, and pointed `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at a directory containing a newer `libc.so.6`. Now the program runs happily :)

Comment: nice hack there!